# Как отсортировать объекты в вложенных массивах по свойству?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты

Есть вот такой массив объектов:

```
[
    [
        {"value": "A", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "G", "level": 1},
            {"value": "B", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "H", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
            {"value": "K", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "M", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "P", "level": 1},
            {"value": "N", "level": 1}
        ]
    ] 
    [
        {"value": "L", "level": 0}
    ],
];
```

Как отсортировать его по свойству `value` не нарушая порядок вложенности, чтобы получилось так:

```
[
    [
        {"value": "A", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "B", "level": 1},
            {"value": "G", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "H", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
            {"value": "K", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "L", "level": 0}
    ],
    [
        {"value": "M", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "N", "level": 1},
            {"value": "P", "level": 1}
        ]
    ] 
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй это

```
    const data = [
    [
        {"value": "A", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "G", "level": 1},
            {"value": "B", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "H", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "J", "level": 1}, 
            {"value": "K", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "M", "level": 0},
        [
            {"value": "P", "level": 1},
            {"value": "N", "level": 1}
        ]
    ],
    [
        {"value": "L", "level": 0}
    ],
    ];

    data.sort(((el1, el2) => {
     if (el1[0].value > el2[0].value) {
    return 1;
     }
     if (el1[0].value < el2[0].value) {
    return -1;
    }
      return 0;
       })).map(el => {
      if (el[1]) {

    el[1].sort((el1, el2) => {
       if (el1.value > el2.value) {
         return 1;
      }
      if (el1.value < el2.value) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    })
  }
})

console.log(data)

// result:
// [
//   [
//     {
//       "value": "A",
//       "level": 0
//     },
//     [
//       {
//         "value": "B",
//         "level": 1
//       },
//       {
//         "value": "G",
//         "level": 1
//       }
//     ]
//   ],
//   [
//     {
//       "value": "H",
//       "level": 0
//     },
//     [
//       {
//         "value": "J",
//         "level": 1
//       },
//       {
//         "value": "K",
//         "level": 1
//       }
//     ]
//   ],
//   [
//     {
//       "value": "L",
//       "level": 0
//     }
//   ],
//   [
//     {
//       "value": "M",
//       "level": 0
//     },
//     [
//       {
//         "value": "N",
//         "level": 1
//       },
//       {
//         "value": "P",
//         "level": 1
//       }
//     ]
//   ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[sortBy из lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sortBy)

Вот. Но с вложенными массивами может быть чуть посложнее